How to calculate possible password permutations
I am currently testing password restrictions for a modelling task, and am finding the number of passwords that meet the minimum requirements. The current restriction is: at least 8 characters, at least 1 number, at least 1 upper-case. Since I am testing the restrictions, and not the passwords, I am trying to calculate the number of possible passwords with EXACTLY 1 number, 1 uppercase and the rest (6 characters) lower case.
I had come up with (26+10)(262)26262626, as, for the first character, there can be a number, 0-9, or one of 26 letters. Then, since one of the letters will be uppercase, the next was 26*2. However, I cannot decide whether this is right, as the first character may be a letter instead. Thanks in advance!

6 lower case has 26^6 possible passwords, add 1 uppercase and you now have 7*26^7 since there are 7 positions the uppercase character could occupy, add 1 number and you now have 8*7*10*26^7 (~4.5*10^12), since there are 8 positions to put the numeric digit in a password of 6 lowercase and one uppercase.

Should the position of the 6 lower case letters also be considered, providing (1026^7)(8!)? If not, can you explain why not? Thank you very much for your assistance.

In the final step, you're only choosing the numeric digit and where to insert it. Everything else is already in the 7 character product.

Ahh that makese sense. Thanks!

I think Simon is correct.
The lowercase letters can be arranged in 6 slots using 26^6.
For the remaining 2 slots, where order doesn't matter, we use combinations instead of permutations.
Therefore, we can place 1 digit in any of the 8 slots, 81=8, which determines the position. So, for this slot, there are 8×10 possibilities, where 10 represents the different digits (0-9).
For the uppercase letters, we have only seven positions since one must be a digit. Therefore, 71=7, and for this slot, we have 26 different uppercase letters.
